Is there any possibility Cloud Run is stripping, or malforming request headers coming from my frontend app?
I'm seriously grasping at straws here.
I have a cloud run app that acts as a basic api. It's ingress is set to all but it requires authentication.
I have a frontend app written in Angular that has a basic http.get. The user signs in using their org Google email, and it grabs the idToken from the user's OIDC. I've tested this works via a curl and it does.
The idea being that my frontend app directly communicates with the Cloud Run app via it's .app.run url and passes in the idToken from the user's login as an auth bearer token:
 const idToken = this.authService.getIDToken(); // retrieved from OIDC
 const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${idToken}`);

 return this.http.get(
    'cloudRunURL',
    { headers, withCredentials: true }
 ).pipe(//other code)

The errors I get in the web developer console are:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://foobar.run.app. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 403.

And the error I get in the Cloud Run logs is:
"The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client"

I've tested by console.log outputting the this.authService.getIDToken() value and manually trying with a curl and it works as expected.
I've also inspected the request headers for the outgoing request and I can see the Bearer token being sent.
So I'm not sure whether this is happening with the "invisible" lb Cloud Run uses with Cloud Run urls. Could something be malforming or stripping my request headers?
Any advice or further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated

Can you check if this link helps.

It appears that this is nothing to do with Cloud Run and is indeed related to the pre-flight request being sent prior to my get request.
This post I believe covers the same issue
